# Update value of state for single item when multiple items share same value in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have created a state using react hook and I have share that state value to n numbers of elements. Now my problem is that I just want to update value for a particular element but all elements are updating that state value. For example if user want to purchase  a particular item one item in a list of items and want to increase that item quantity, and I have created a state { const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1) }. Now if user add quantity for x item , y and z who both also use quantity as their value is also getting increased, but I want that only x quantity should increase. I hope I have elaborated it just fine so you all can understand. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Each time should be stored in an object containing only information concerning that item. If you have multiples items then, the state will be an array of items.

Comment: You should create one state for each element to control and make sense

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, simply create an `Array` that contains the state information about your items:

```js
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { itemName: "x", quantity: 0 },
    { itemName: "y", quantity: 0 },
    { itemName: "z", quantity: 0 },
  ]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    let updated = [...items];
    updated[e.target.id].quantity++;
    setItems(updated);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <button id={index} onClick={handleClick}>
          {item.itemName}: {item.quantity}
        </button>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an array.  When using an array you need to merge the old state with the new state and check that you're updating the correct item.

```
  import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const updateItem = useCallback(
    (props) => { // props - item being added, updated, or removed
      setItems((prevItems) => { // prevItems - items that were already in state
        const newArray = [...prevItems]; // cast to a new array to tell react to update/rerender
        const i = newArray.findIndex((old) => old.id === props.id); // check if item is already in state
        if (i > -1) { // item is in state - remove or update
          const newQty = props.qty;
          if (newQty === 0) {
            newArray.splice(i, 1); // remove item qty is 0
          } else {
            newArray[i].qty = newQty; // qty is not 0 - update qty
          }
        } else{
           newArray.push(props); // not in state add to state
        }
        return newArray; // update state and rerender
      });
    },
    [setItems]
  );
```

Here is a complete working example -
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-86lw2?file=/src/index.js